# Visual Studio 2015 folder suggestions does not pop up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Usually when I try to type using @Styles.Render("") it gives me folder suggestions in my solution explorer.

Now I type into @Styles.Render() it doesn't give me any folder suggestions.

[image]

I am using Visual Studio MVC.

Comment: This is a story about your setup, what is your question?

Comment: @Styles.Render("~/fonts/font-awesome/css") is a code I used. And when I start typing @Styles.Render("~/fonts/.....")  I want to be able to start getting suggestions for the folder.

Comment: that is binding issue there is one folder app_start  under that you will found one binding related class . bind all your css and js files there and just call this method in view  page wherever you want to render.for more info check the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270834/asp-net-mvc-bundle-not-rendering-script-files-on-staging-server-it-works-on-dev

Comment: Thank you very much sir, if you post it as answer I will mark it as correct.