# ASP.NET Bundling and minification doesn't work in Webforms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to use bundling in a project I have in ASP.net Webforms VB.net.

This is what I have done:

Added the reference to Web.Optimization
Added the following  in my Application_start in the global.asax

```
   BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = True
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jsglobal").Include("~/js/inlineValidate.js"))
```

and the following in my master file

```
  <%:Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jsglobal")%>
```

But it just show me this in the rendered page,

```
  <script src="/bundles/jsglobal"></script>
```

Which not only it doesn't have the unique query string but also it doesn't exist.

Not sure what the problem is, I did exactly the same thing in ASP.net MVC C# and it works fine.

Comment: How do you added Web.Optimization to your project?

Comment: I added it through nuget

Comment: Which NuGet package did you use? Web.Optimization or Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization?
There is even a Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms if you go the Microsoft route.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're seeing is expected. To test, turn BundleTable.EnableOptimizations to FALSE. Or just omit the line, it will be handled automatically.

[ASP.NET MVC Bundle not rendering script files on staging server. It works on development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270834/asp-net-mvc-bundle-not-rendering-script-files-on-staging-server-it-works-on-dev)