# Angular and Bootstrap not added to Bundle in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, bootstrap-4

I have specified the Angular and bootstrap in the Bundle.config file as

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                     "~/Scripts/angular-*",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
```

and I had specified these bundles in Layout.cshtml file inside the body as

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Inside the Global.asax file I had specified the Budleconfig in `Application_Start()` as

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
```

even though the Angular and Bootstrap files are not been Bundled Can anyone please point me what I am missing here

Note: I have checked the path it is correct.

[image: Angular and Bootstrap JS path]

[image: Bootstrap CSS Path]

Comment: have you tried setting the path to "~/Content/Scripts/......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Bundle not rendering script files on staging server. It works on development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270834/asp-net-mvc-bundle-not-rendering-script-files-on-staging-server-it-works-on-dev)

Comment: please do check if Webgrease is installed.

Comment: What's the function declaration look like where you are registering the bundles.  Unless I'm mistaken, a lot of this is done by convention, and if you have the function name wrong, it might not be registering anything?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I had checked the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270834/asp-net-mvc-bundle-not-rendering-script-files-on-staging-server-it-works-on-dev already, I have Webgrease Installed but it is not working