# C# MVC bundling not working with Angular Elements Web Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular-elements, asp.net-bundling

I'm using Angular Elements in C# MVC project.

When I include angular elements build file directly in `main.cshtml` like
`<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Script/Angular/artifi-graphics.js"></script>` it's working perfectly.

BUT

when I try to add build file in the bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Layout_8_CommonModule")
                .Include("~/Script/Angular/artifigraphics.js")
```

then the project is not loading.

In console network status of the request is pending and after some time it gets failed.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Bundle not rendering script files on staging server. It works on development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270834/asp-net-mvc-bundle-not-rendering-script-files-on-staging-server-it-works-on-dev)

Comment: @RahulSharma already tried this solution but not working

Comment: Okay, have you tried this link: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/bundling-and-minifying-an-angularjs-application-with-asp-net-mvc

Comment: yes tried this also but no luck

Comment: Unlike .NET references, Javascript files need to load based on the order. Angular App should be loaded first, then the related components. You would have to include it in the app file using `Include` method instead of `IncludeDirectory` method.

Comment: I tried with `Include` and `IncludeDirectory` but still not working, created saperate bundle though but still not working.

Comment: Not quite sure but usually this happens when some extension is blocking your request that is why it is in `pending` status. Try disabling some Chrome extensions like `Adblocker` and then try again.

Comment: actually, when I debug CS code the pointer is getting stuck on bundling, and also tried in incognito mode and disabling adblocker extension as you suggested but still no luck

Comment: Okay, are you including a `_Layout` from your Shared folder for your View or is your page without a common layout? And what do you mean by "debug CS code the pointer is getting stuck on bundling"? Is it throwing some error?

Comment: Did you get this resolved ?

Comment: no @RahulSharma, I googled a lot and find out minified js unable to bundle with regular js in c# bundling

Comment: so basically I just add script tag in `main.cshtml` file just like including the normal script in HTML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after searching a lot find out C# bundling is not so intelligent to bundle angular production build files which are also merged by `node concat` library.

so I just added `angular` bundle into `main.cshtml` file just like we add scripts.