# MVC JS Bundle not including all files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

I've seen questions about this elsewhere but they all were about bundling .min files.  In my case I have a couple of js files in a bundle but only one is being included as far as I can see.  Everything builds but if I look at the page source or the bundle in chrome developer tools, only one js file is included.  Bundle looks like this:

```
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myJS").Include(
                  "~/myJS/getPathforAjax.js", 
                  "~/myJS/dropdown.js",
                  "~/myJS/email8.js",
                  "~/myJS/main-nav-click.js"
                  ));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                 "~/Content/site.css"
                 ,"~/Content/caption.css"
                 , "~/Content/dropdown.css"
                 , "~/Content/colors.css"
                 , "~/Content/buttons.css"
                 , "~/Content/stripe.css"));
    }
```

The css files all load but in the myJS bundle only email8 looks to be included and it is minimized. I would think that if there was a js error then none of the files would show or they would show non-minimized  All the files are where they are supposed to be on the server.  I have reloaded, hard reloaded, etc, but they don't pop up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

and try this code it's work for me in my project very first I'm adding min file in bundles it's not including then I'm added this line.

**BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;**

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myJS").Include(
                  "~/myJS/getPathforAjax.js", 
                  "~/myJS/dropdown.js",
                  "~/myJS/email8.js",
                  "~/myJS/main-nav-click.js"
                  ));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                 "~/Content/site.css"
                 ,"~/Content/caption.css"
                 , "~/Content/dropdown.css"
                 , "~/Content/colors.css"
                 , "~/Content/buttons.css"
                 , "~/Content/stripe.css"));

         // Code removed for clarity.
          BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that last line of code but still just getting the one file in the bundle.  I will have to read that article more closely.  I've used bundles before with no problem so this is very frustrating

Comment: When you added all file in bundle it's automatically convert in one file please check msdn for more details

Comment: I know that's what its supposed to do but when I de-minimize the bundle in chrome developer tools it only shows the email8.js file.

Comment: Can we connect way TV or any desk?

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270834/asp-net-mvc-bundle-not-rendering-script-files-on-staging-server-it-works-on-dev)

Comment: Ok I added that extra code and had to do a couple hard resets on chrome and now its working,  Thanks for the help.

Comment: must appreciated brother :).