# Asp.net webform Bundling Missing 404

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification

I have tried implementing Bundling in Asp.net webform projects.
My Bundleconfig:

```
            System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new System.Web.Optimization.ScriptBundle("~/bundle/LoginPageJS")
                  .Include("~/assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js", "~/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js", "~/assets/js/validatr.js", "~/assets/js/jquery.placeholder.js"));

            System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle("~/bundle/LoginPageCSS")
                 .Include("~/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css", "~/assets/styles/stylesheet.css",
                 "~/assets/styles/non-responsive.css", "~/assets/styles/Window.css", "~/IACMSkin/Window.IACMSkin.css"));

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

MasterPage:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>My Sample</title>

        <%: @Styles.Render("~/bundle/LoginPageCSS") %>
        <%: @Scripts.Render("~/bundle/LoginPageJS") %>
</head>
```

It's working in my local machine as well as VM(Windows server 2016 IIS10) and not in UAT environment.

The difference I see here is 
Below is from my local and VM:

```
<link href="/bundle/LoginPageCSS?v=1FyFAVt-XUmly2H-AbvXacpx3b4ou5J-Tsk2Ac5PxaE1" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/bundle/LoginPageJS?v=Kw5fkDuqDSQdMcwvucaZg-o1ChJ6qAulChBWIhFdZhc1"></script>
```

Below is from UAT:404 error

```
<link href="/bundle/LoginPageCSS" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/bundle/LoginPageJS"></script>
```

I checked debug="false" as well.

Please help

Comment: The information in this post regarding a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270834/asp-net-mvc-bundle-not-rendering-script-files-on-staging-server-it-works-on-dev) might help.

Comment: I have verified the given link still didn't help.